# Mobile emulators

Tags: responsive-design, media-queries, fluid-layout

I'm developing a new Responsive layout for different smart phones, tablets etc, so i require a single emulator to test for all the devices. Like to know if any one have used any thing.

Note: I have used media queries and flexible layout for my design

Answer (score 0):

First i would recommend you test your applications/websites or real devices.
If it's not possible for you to get those then there are few suggestions.

> [Opera Mobile Emulator](http://www.opera.com/developer/tools/mobile/) ( It provides significant varieties of different view-ports. You can also test on your own custom View-port.)
> There are some online tools also to test your websites/applications.
>
> [Responsinator](http://www.responsinator.com) ( Just put your live URL [there](http://responsinator.com) and get your website's responsiveness on different devices' view-ports. )

Hope you'll have better ideas.